# Patching default value of the field

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-unittest

I have a model with `uuid` field with default value as a function.

```py
from uuid import uuid4

def _new_uid():
    return uuid4()


class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    uid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=_new_uid, editable=False)
```

In test I want to patch `_new_uid` method return `11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111`.

```py
@patch('module.foo._new_uid',
       Mock(return_value='11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'))
def test_create_A():
    response = api_client.post('/api/a-list/', {
        'name': 'test',
    })

    assert response.json() == {
        '_uid': '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
        'name': 'test'
    }
```

But it still returns some random uuid. I guess it's happening because model initialization is over before test start running.

I can avoid it by changing default option to:

```
uid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=lambda: _new_uid(), editable=False)
```

Can it be done without changing `default` to lambda call?

Comment: Are `_new_uid` and `A` in the file `module.foo.py`?

Comment: @DipenDadhaniya yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to solve this issue.

Need to change import statement of `uuid4`

```
import uuid

def _new_uid():
    return uuid.uuid4()
```

And now I'm able to patch uuid

```
@patch('module.foo._new_uid',
       Mock(**{'uuid4.return_value': '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'}))
def test_create_A():
    response = api_client.post('/api/v1/a-list/', {
        'name': 'test',
    })

   assert response.json() == {
        '_uid': '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
        'name': 'test'
    }
```